# Flutter: overflowed by Infinty Pixels on the buttom ( Below is the code

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-layoutbuilder

RenderPhysicalModel object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
package:financy/Authentication/verify_email_page.dart:66
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

```
  class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
        child: Builder(builder: (context) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Signed in as',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              Text(
                user.email!,
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 40,
              ),
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
                ),
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back,
                  size: 32,
                ),
                label: Text(
                  'Sign Out',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                ),
                onPressed: () => FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(),
              )
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wrap Scaffold body with `SIngleChildScrollView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap you scaffold Body with single child scroll view like below -

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
          child: Builder(builder: (context) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Signed in as',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                Text(
                  user.email!,
                  style:
                  TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                ),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
                  ),
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                    size: 32,
                  ),
                  label: Text(
                    'Sign Out',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(),
                )
              ],
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```